# How to scan credit or debit card in android using card.io

Tags: android

I am developing application to scan debit and credit card by using card.io library.my application can scan only the card contains engraved numbers.But i need to scan all type of cards. please suggest me to scan all type of cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Activity or Fragment you have to start Card.io activity using `startActivityForResult` like:

```
private int CARD_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
Intent scanIntent = new Intent(activity, CardIOActivity.class);

scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_POSTAL_CODE, false);
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, true);
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true);
scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, true);

startActivityForResult(scanIntent, CARD_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and then you get the response in `onActivityResult` like:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CARD_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (data != null && data.hasExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT))
        {
            CreditCard scanResult = data.getParcelableExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT);
            //TODO: get data from scanResult
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done the code as like you said but am not getting scan result

Comment: where are you putting this code, activity or fragment?

Comment: I placed my code in activity

Comment: is your scanning screen recognizing card number and closing and you just don't get the data, or your scanning screen do not close at all?

Comment: i just didn't get the data

Comment: the above code is working but only few type of cards scaning

Comment: oh, ok, I worked only with MasterCard